# Downloading pdf file with puppeteer

Tags: pdf, download, puppeteer

How can I download .pdf file with node puppeteer?
I tried retrieve buffer data with page.on('load') event, but I'm getting only hash like this: 3a42112c-8d3e-474e-af0f-2e482520bc25

Comment: Can we see a code example?

Comment: Can you try using express.js to response pdf file? Like my answer at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48542991/puppeteer-pdf-blank-on-heroku/52629153#52629153)